# Find the number of active rooms created by Socket.io in redis server using redis-cli

Tags: redis, socket.io

I have created Socket.io Platform where I am using Redis-Adapter as io.adapter. I want to get number of active rooms from Redis-Server when it is connected by N number of Socket-Server.
Also, Using "PUBSUB CHANNELS" I am receiving 2 channels as "socket.io-request#/#" & "socket.io-response#/#".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Perhaps the [`PUBSUB CHANNELS *`](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub) command can help here.

Comment: i have used the redis-cli command PUBSUB CHANNELS.But it will only provide the list of active channels.I have to find the number of active rooms in a  redis channel.